# How to Pass columns contained in a declared variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, dynamic-sql

I have a table `Depots` that looks like this:

| DepotID | DepotName | DepotLocation | DepAlias |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ouland | Utsacity | Oula |
| 2 | Ingri | Utsacity | Inglas |
| 3 | Turks | Utsacity | Turku |
| 4 | tamps | Uusimaa | Tampere |
| 5 | Kokos | Uusimaa | Kokoola |
| 6 | Kaus | Olomba | Kaukana |

I stored a comma-separated list of columns in a declared variable `@ValList`

```
DECLARE @ValList varchar(8000);
SET @ValList = NULL

SELECT @ValList = COALESCE(@ValList + ', ','') + ColumnName 
FROM #list
```

`@ValList` returns `DepotID, DepotName, DepLocation`

I want to pass `@ValList` into a select statement like below

```
SELECT @ValList FROM Depots
```

So that I get

| DepotID | DepotName | DepotLocation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ouland | Utsacity |
| 2 | Ingri | Utsacity |
| 3 | Turks | Utsacity |
| 4 | tamps | Uusimaa |
| 5 | Kokos | Uusimaa |
| 6 | Kaus | Olomba |

But I keep getting something like

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| DepotID, DepotName, DepLocation |
| DepotID, DepotName, DepLocation |
| DepotID, DepotName, DepLocation |
| DepotID, DepotName, DepLocation |
| DepotID, DepotName, DepLocation |
| DepotID, DepotName, DepLocation |

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does this list of column names come from?

Comment: Looks dangerous: make sure you use a whitelist of column names to check against, do not just take user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem interested in dynamic TSQL. Try using [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) Eg.

```sql
DECLARE @ValList varchar(8000);
SET @ValList = 'DepotID, DepotName, DepotLocation';

SELECT @ValList as ColumnNames;

DECLARE @MyQuery NVARCHAR(4000) = CONCAT(N'SELECT ',@ValList,N' FROM  Depots');

EXECUTE sp_executesql @MyQuery;
```

| ColumnNames |
| --- |
| DepotID, DepotName, DepotLocation |

| DepotID | DepotName | DepotLocation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ouland | Utsacity |
| 2 | Ingri | Utsacity |
| 3 | Turks | Utsacity |
| 4 | tamps | Uusimaa |
| 5 | Kokos | Uusimaa |
| 6 | Kaus | Olomba |

[View working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9c8ebe7a06fc3d059daff94e3777b8c9)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you @ggordon, this worked really well

Comment: @Mikko Note that this is _easy_, and _works_, but if that comma-separated list is ultimately coming from an end user, it is not _safe_.

Comment: could you use this to return aggregate results for the specified columns? for example count the number of NULL rows in each column?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how much you can or should trust the source of the list of columns, but the safest way to do this is as follows, where you check the existence of each column in `sys.columns`:

```
CREATE TABLE #list(ColumnName sysname);

INSERT #list(ColumnName) 
VALUES(N'DepotID'),(N'DepotName'),(N'DepLocation');

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @cols nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @cols += N',' + QUOTENAME(c.name) 
  FROM #List AS l
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
  ON l.ColumnName = c.name
  WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Depots');
  
SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + STUFF(@cols, 1, 1, N'') 
  + N' FROM dbo.Depots';
  
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=27c6c12a66876d95250d2f0c594d2542)

Protecting yourself from SQL injection: [Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-1/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) | [Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)