# Return aggregate results per column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

Suppose I have a table like so:

| ID | Purchases | Quantity | Products |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 5 | 7 | 2 |
| 002 | 12 | 24 | 9 |

Is there a way in SQL where I can return aggregate information about each column like so:

| Column | Min | Max | Avg | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Purchases | 5 | 12 | 6.5 | 2 |
| Quantity | 7 | 24 | 14.6 | 3 |
| Products | 2 | 9 | 3.7 | 4 |

I can define a list of columns I want to return metrics on with `DECLARE`

```
DECLARE @METRICS VARCHAR(8000);
SET @METRICS = 'Purchases, Quantity', 'Products';
SELECT @METRICS AS ColumnNames;
```

But then how to write a `SELECT` statement that returns the aggregated results?

I thought I could do something like this based on @ggordon response here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69600079/2430558, but my declared variable is a list

```
DECLARE @MyQuery NVARCHAR(4000) = CONCAT(N'
    SELECT 
    AVG(', @METRICS, N') AS Col_Avg
    FROM mytable GROUP BY', @METRICS);

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @MyQuery;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: we are using MS SQL

Comment: Your query doesn't make much sense as it stands: you are grouping and aggregating by the same columns

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use separate queries for each row and combine them to one result with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT
  'Purchases' AS "column",
  MIN(Purchases) AS min,
  MAX(Purchases) AS max,
  ROUND(AVG(Purchases),2) AS avg,
  COUNT(Purchases) AS count
FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'Quantity' AS "column",
  MIN(Quantity) AS min,
  MAX(Quantity) AS max,
  ROUND(AVG(Quantity),2) AS avg,
  COUNT(Quantity) AS count
FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'Products' AS "column",
  MIN(Products) AS min,
  MAX(Products) AS max,
  ROUND(AVG(Products),2) AS avg,
  COUNT(Products) AS count
FROM mytable;
```

This will produce from your sample data...

| ID | Purchases | Quantity | Products |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 5 | 7 | 2 |
| 002 | 12 | 24 | 9 |

...following result:

| column | min | max | avg | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Purchases | 5 | 12 | 8.50 | 2 |
| Quantity | 7 | 24 | 15.50 | 2 |
| Products | 2 | 9 | 5.50 | 2 |

I don't know how you will get different values in the column "count" from your sample data. I guess this will happen if some of the columns are `NULL`.
See this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WVFljYsk) example. I added another row to the sample data where the Quantity is `NULL`. Then the result will be this one:

| column | min | max | avg | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Purchases | 5 | 12 | 9.00 | 3 |
| Quantity | 7 | 24 | 15.50 | 2 |
| Products | 2 | 20 | 10.33 | 3 |

Comment: Formatting queries makes them much easier to read and understand

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for this, but while this is a solution to the specific table, what if I wanted to apply this query to another table? I would need to add another union module and replace the column name in all the aggregates - MIN(), MAX(), AVG(), etc... I'm looking for something where I can just change a list of columns in one place

Comment: @DrPaulVella In my opinion, that is another question/another step and should be answered in a separate question. Please keep in mind the guidelines here say one question per question. This makes it easier for other people with similar questions to find solutions for their issues.